# error while handle regex

Tags: c#, regex, split, text-files

hye, I got this error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.dll" while doing this split code. the error occur at code textBox1.Text= mc[0].Groups[1].Value;

```
        var desiredText = File.ReadLines(location).ElementAt(i);
        string s = desiredText.ToString();
        //textBox3.Text = s;
        Regex r = new Regex(@"[(.+?)]");
        MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(s);
        textBox1.Text= mc[0].Groups[1].Value;
        textBox2.Text= mc[1].Groups[1].Value;
        textBox3.Text = mc[2].Groups[1].Value;
```

where did I do wrong? the textfile that I used have this data

```
[1] [apple] [market]
[2][toy]asdv[shop]sdvdsrdt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex should probably [escape the square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231637/c-sharp-regular-expression-to-match-square-brackets):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\[(.+?)\]");
```

Answer (score 1):

**In Regex, `[Brackets]` define a Character Class**

- In regex, `[brackets]` have a special meaning: they define a character class. A character class matches one of the characters it contains. For instance, `[abc]` matches either an `a`, a `b` or a `c`. You can also define a range: `[a-c]` matches the same characters.
- The regex `[(.+?)]` therefore matches one single character that is either a `(`, a `)`, a `+` or a `?`
- To match actual brackets, you need to escape them with a `\`. This is what you want: `\[(.+?)\]`

Therefore, in C#:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\[(.+?)\]");
```

**Reference**

[Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Answer (score 1):

The way you have your brackets, the regular expression engine considers it as a [**Character Class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) matching any of those characters that are placed inside. You need to [**escape**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) your brackets in order to match a literal.

```
string s = @"[1] [apple] [market]";

Regex r = new Regex(@"\[(.+?)\]");
MatchCollection mc = r.Matches(s);

Console.WriteLine(mc[0].Groups[1].Value); //=> 1
Console.WriteLine(mc[1].Groups[1].Value); //=> apple
Console.WriteLine(mc[2].Groups[1].Value); //=> market
```